# ip-config-unavailable DHCP error from NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

### Overview and Environment

I recently set up a new VirtualBox VM and ran into some strange network behavior. The machine is running Ubuntu 22.04 and after installing the virtualbox guest additions, my I was unable to access the internet. The interface connected to the internet (enp0s3) is set up to use a bridged adapter to my wireless interface on the host machine.

### Diagnosis steps

The first thing I did was to check the logs from Network Manager to see what was going on and noticed that enp0s3 was unable to connect

```
Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (adea0206-d268-302b-b1d3-6f12a938a5db)
device (enp0s3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp0s3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp0s3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
dhcp4 (enp0s3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
device (enp0s3): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

I then used Wireshark to look at the DHCP Packets and noticed that the Vm was sending a discover packet, my home router (192.168.1.1) was sending an offer packet, the VM was responding with a request packet, and the router was responding with an acknowledgment packet. This showed me that there was no issue with the actual DHCP transaction.

I tried reapplying the netplan configuration and rebooting the system but neither of these resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

After a little bit of digging, I found out that occasionally, the NetworkManager Configuration can become corrupted. Unfortunately, I didn't save the corrupted file to see what actually went wrong. The configuration file is located at `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. I simply removed this file and restarted NetworkManager and everything is working again

#### Commands Ran

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

**Note:** a better alternative to removing the configuration file is to move it to a different location. `sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf ~/NetworkManager.conf.bac`

#### Successful Connection output

```
dhcp4 (enp0s3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
device (enp0s3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume')
device (enp0s3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume')
device (enp0s3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume')
device (enp0s3): Activation: successful, device activated.
```